# Xpath - selection based on multiple criteria

Tags: c#, xpath

I have the following XML File:

```
<persons>
   <person name="shawn">
      <age>34</age>
      <hair style="spikes">red</hair>
    </person>
    <person  name="mike">
       <age>36</age>
       <hair style="bald">red</hair>
    </person>
    <person name="shawn">
       <age>38</age>
       <hair style="bald">red</hair>
    </person>
</persons>
```

Using XPath in C#, is it possible to select the person element where the name is "Shawn", and the hair style = "bald"?

I tried using:

```
XElement.XPathSelectElement("//person[@name='shawn'] | //person/hair[@style='bald']
```

but that gives me a reference to the hair element, and not the person element.

Thanks in advance :)

Peter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want someone who is both called shawn and is bald (which your question title suggests), you want:

```
//person[@name='shawn' and hair/@style='bald']
```

If you want people who are either called shawn or are bald (which it looks like you may do from the attempt in your question), you want:

```
//person[@name='shawn' or hair/@style='bald']
```

Comment: Thanks, your first statement did the trick. My mistake was to close the square bracket prior to the and. I tried several combinations, but never took into account both the search strings had to be within the same set of square brackets.

Comment: They don't. The expression `//person[@name='shawn'][hair/@style='bald']` would work equally well. Whatever your mistake was, it wasn't this.